# How i can find a role with space?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

So I'm trying to create a bot, which will give a role users that bought it in a store *!buy*

On the Internet, I found 2 ways to search for a role, and they do not help me, i have a role with a space, and the bot does not want to look for it

````
  let author = db.fetch(`money_${message.author.id}`)

  if (args[0] == 'Coin Owner 500k') {
    if (author < 500000) return message.channel.send('You need at least 500000 coins')

    message.guild.members.get(message.author.id).roles.add(message.guild.roles.get('Coin Owner 500k')

    db.subtract(`money_${message.author.id}`, 500000)
    message.channel.send(message.author.tag + 'Role added to you!')

  }


}```
````

Answer (score 0):

`get` method will try to retrieve a role thanks to it's ID, in your code it's like if you are saying "I want the role that have the ID `Coin Owner 500k`" but you actually need to get it by name, not by ID.

So, to get a role by it's name you can use the `find` method like that :

```js
// This will return the role named "Coin Owner 500k" if it exists
message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Coin Owner 500k");
```

(Note that getting a role by it's ID through `get` method is more efficient, you can get the ID of the role you wish by right clicking it on Discord and hit "Copy Identifier")

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Coin Owner 500k')` though

Comment: Yes you're right! Thank you for correction, had little inattention when answering.